# При каких значениях m и n прямые параллельны?

Tags: математика

Насколько я знаю, для того, чтобы прямые были параллельными, их угловые коэффициенты должны быть равны. Однако для того, чтобы эти угловые коэф. найти, необходимо, чтобы уравнения были приведены к уравнению с угловым коэффициентом, собственно. Однако ниже представлена одна из двух прямых, которая образована путём пересечения двух плоскостей, а другая — в каноничном виде. И совершенно непонятно, каким образом достать коэффициенты, сравнить их, чтобы найти m, а затем n значения. Пытался различными способами преобразовать каждую из них, но не уверен в правильности своих действий, и не всегда получалось вообще. Если будет не сложно, подскажите как минимум алгоритм, если не решение. Заранее спасибо.

[image: При каких значениях m и n прямые параллельны?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение Вашей  проблемы :

- коэффициенты в уравнении плоскостей определяют векторы, нормальные к плоскости, следовательно их векторное произведение дает вектор `V`, задающий направление линии пересечения. В Вашей задаче нормаль к первой плоскости это вектор `p1=[m,0,-3]`, ко второй `p2=[1,2,0]`, соответственно `V=P1xP2` или `V=[m,0,8]x[1,2,0]` (Надеюсь, что формулу для векторного произведения трех-мерных векторов Вы найдете в Интернет)
- условие коллинеарности двух векторов - это равенство нулю их векторного произведения. Координаты вектора, определяющего направление второй прямой, - это коэффициенты в ее каноническом представлении, которое Вам дано по условию задачи, то есть `Q=[n,-6,4]`. Соответственно отсюда имеем искомое уравнение, связывающее `m` и `n`:

`V x Q = 0` или ([m,0,8]x[1,2,0])x[n,-6,4] = 0

Вам осталось лишь расписать векторные произведения, на всякий случай ссылка https://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/library/vector/multiply1/

Comment: Премного благодарен.

Comment: @Leon Scarp, рад что помог. Буду Вам признателен, если мой ответ, Вы пометите, как решение. Соответственно это вопрос перейдет в разряд решенных и не будет отвлекать посетителей форума, а Вы добавите себе и мне балов в карму :)

Comment: Сделано. Желаю удачи!

Comment: Нормаль первой плоскости разве не p1=[m,0,-3] ?

Comment: @Leon Scarp - да, моя опечатка